# C# Increasing performance of a Linked List

Tags: c#, data-structures, stack, doubly-linked-list

I'm working on SPOJ problem where you have to write an algorithm that based on input string conditions outputs new string, but you can't exceede time limit.
[problem link](https://www.spoj.com/problems/NABILHACKER/)

The fastest i could get was by using two stacks, but time limit was still exceeded, now I tried implementing doubly linked list, but it's twice slower than when I used stack. Do you have any idea on how can I increase performance of implemented linked list, or maybe should I use other data structure for this problem? Thought of implementing Node as a structure but not really sure if you can do that.

```
using System;


namespace spoj
{
    class LinkedList
    {
        private Node head;
        private Node tail;
        private int length;

        public Node Head { get => head; }
        public Node Tail { get => tail; }
        public int Length { get => length; }

        public LinkedList(Node head = null, Node tail = null, int length = 0)
        {
            this.head = head;
            this.tail = tail;
            this.length = length;
        }

        public void AddFirst(char value)
        {
            var addFirst = new Node(value);
            addFirst.Next = head;
            addFirst.Previous = null;
            if (head != null)
                head.Previous = addFirst;
            head = addFirst;
            length++;
        }

        public void Remove(Node node)
        {
            if (node.Previous == null)
            {
                head = node.Next;
                head.Previous = null;
                length--;
            }
            else if (node.Next == null)
            {
                tail = node.Previous;
                tail.Next = null;
                length--;
            }
            else
            {
                Node temp1 = node.Previous;
                Node temp2 = node.Next;
                temp1.Next = temp2;
                temp2.Previous = temp1;
                length--;
            }
        }

        public void AddAfter(Node node, char input)
        {
            var newNode = new Node(input);
            if (node.Next == null)
            {
                node.Next = newNode;
                newNode.Previous = node;
                length++;
            }
            else
            {
                Node temp1 = node;
                Node temp2 = node.Next;
                temp1.Next = newNode;
                newNode.Previous = temp1;
                newNode.Next = temp2;
                temp2.Previous = newNode;
                length++;
            }
        }

        public string Print()
        {
            string temp = "";
            if (head == null)
                return temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                temp += head.Value;
                head = head.Next;
            }
            return temp;
        }


    }
    class Node
    {
        private char value;
        private Node next;
        private Node previous;

        public char Value { get => value; }
        public Node Next { get => next; set { next = value; } }
        public Node Previous { get => previous; set { previous = value; } }

        public Node(char value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            next = null;
            previous = null;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int testNum = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < testNum; i++)
            {
                var list = new LinkedList();
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                var node = list.Head;

                for (int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++)
                {
                    if ((input[j] == '<' && node == null) | (input[j] == '>' && (node == null || node.Next == null)) | (input[j] == '-' && (node == null || node.Previous == null)))
                        continue;
                    else if (input[j] == '<')
                    {
                        node = node.Previous;
                    }
                    else if (input[j] == '>')
                    {
                        node = node.Next;
                    }
                    else if (input[j] == '-')
                    {
                        node = node.Previous;
                        list.Remove(node.Next);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (node == null)
                        {
                            list.AddFirst(input[j]);
                            node = list.Head;
                            continue;
                        }
                        list.AddAfter(node, input[j]);
                        node = node.Next;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(list.Print());
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: why not just use StringBuilder

Comment: I mean its 15 lines of code

Comment: Where in that problem do they mention that you shall implement a linked list?

Comment: I didn't say they mentioned implementing linked list, I implemented linked list thinking I will be able to increase its performance, and asked on how to do that since can't figure it out myself. I didn't know about String Builder and never used it, but thanks for advice, I'm going to familiarize myself with that class.

Comment: > tarun_28: 2020-09-22 19:44:58 Solved using linked list;)

Comment: Yeah I saw that comment, that is also why I tried solving it using linked list but it exceedes time limit when implemented in c#, not sure if that is a problem with algorithm itself, or c# linked list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implementation using a linked list will not be as fast as one that uses [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0), but assuming you are asking about a linked  list based implementation I would suggest not to reimplement `LinkedList`. Just use the [native one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-6.0).

This means you don't have to change much in your code, just this:

- Define the type of the list nodes as `char`: `new LinkedList<char>();`
- Instead of `.Head` use `.First`
- Instead of `.Print` use `string.Join("", list)`

However, there are these problems in your code:

- When the input is `>`, you should allow the logic to execute when `node` is `null`. Currently you `continue`, but a `null` may mean that your "cursor" is in front of the non-empty list, so you should still deal with it, and move the "cursor" to `list.First`
- When the input is `-`, you should still perform the removal even when `node.Previous` is `null`, because it is not the *previous* node that gets removed, but the *current* node. We should imagine the cursor to be between two consecutive nodes, and your removal logic shows that you took as rule that the cursor is between the current `node` and `node.Next`. You could also have taken another approach (with the cursor is just *before* `node`), but important is that all your logic is consistent with this choice.
- When executing the logic for `-` -- in line with the previous point -- you should take into account that `node.Previous` could be `null`, and in that case you cannot do the removal as you have it. Instead, you could first assign the node reference to a temporary variable, then move the cursor, and then delete the node that is referenced by the temporary reference.

Here is the corrected code, using the native `LinkedList` implementation. I moved the logic for doing nothing (your `continue`) inside each separate case, as I find that easier to understand/debug:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int testNum = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < testNum; i++)
        {
            var list = new LinkedList<char>();
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            var node = list.First;
            for (int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++)
            {
                if (input[j] == '<')
                {
                    if (node != null)
                        node = node.Previous;
                }
                else if (input[j] == '>')
                {
                    if (node == null || node.Next != null)
                        node = node == null ? list.First : node.Next;
                }
                else if (input[j] == '-')
                {
                    if (node != null) {
                        var temp = node;
                        node = node.Previous;
                        list.Remove(temp);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    node = node == null ? list.AddFirst(input[j]) 
                                        : list.AddAfter(node, input[j]);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", list));
        }
    }
}
```